# Transfer object collection between client and server

Tags: java, oop, sockets, client-server

Is there a way to transfer a set of objects between a server and a client, so that if a change is made either on the server or on the client, the objects will be the same on both the server and the client? And if one object is added, with some connections to other objects, is it possible to transfer only this, and maintain these connections on the other end?

Comment: What kind of client are you thinking of?

Comment: Calendar system for employees in a imaginary business. They can add meetings and appointments to this calendar, and view other employees calendars

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Copy of same data object on client and server or one global data object that client and server can update at the same time?

Comment: I mean what kind of client language? Java? Web? Javascript?

Comment: Tagged as Java :) 
I am trying to have the same set of identical objects in the model on the server and the client. The server will save this to a file. The client will on startup connect to the server and get the data from there. If one client does a change, the server gets updated, and all other connected clients get this update.

Answer (score 0):

How do you transfer single objects? Are you using serializable java objects over TCP? Web service over HTTP? Something proprietary?

Anyway you can do the same with collections of objects. If you are using "standard" serialization mechanism most chances it already supports collections. For example all standard collections provided JDK are serializable and therefore can be easily sent and received. The same is about web services.

Please do not hesitate to ask more concrete questions. If you provide more data we can give you better and more concrete answers.

Comment: As it is, the only thing I have figured out is to use a TCP connection with java sockets.